# How to logout from my app and go to the init login view?

Tags: ios, authentication, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, logout

I have a login view and if the user input the correct name and password and pressed the login button.Then it comes to the home page which is a view embedded in navigation controller and then embedded in tab bar controller ,in one of the page of tab bar controller ,there's a button said logout. when the user puts down that button, the view goes back to the init login page.How to programing wrote that in object-c.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user first time open the app and there is no active session set your `LoginViewController` as `rootViewController` of window. Now when user successfully login the app set your `tabBarController` as `rootViewController` and then your `navigationViewController` as part of `tabBarController`. When user again press the logout button set your `loginViewController` as `rootViewController` of window.

I hope you understand the flow if any doubt can ask me again.

Comment: yep, would do it in the same way! :)

Comment: @leizh007 Are you sure that you have set the storyboard identifier of loginViewController page same as "loginViewController" in storyBoard xib

Answer (score 0):

You can use segues. Draw a segue from the main screen to the login screen and give it a identifier name. When there is a event( may be touch up inside) on the logout button, call the method `performSegueWithIdentifier` on your view controller. It will take you to the login screen.

Comment: That would't work.Because my login view is a single view that don't have a tab bar or a navigation bar ,if i use segues to do that, the login view will have a tab bar and navigation bar,it's weird. The first answer solved my question. Thank you all the same.